# need to store value after passing to method for latter check

Tags: java

I am passing few values to mail method for sending the details like below

```
private static String getTeam(String Team, List<String> prioritys1, String number,String description
           ) {
        StringBuilder builder1 = new StringBuilder();


        for (String v : prioritys1) {

             if ( v == "1")      {
                                       Integer cnt1 = count1.get(new Team(Team, v,number,description));
                                       if (cnt1 == null) {
                                           cnt1 = 0;
                                       }
                            else
                                       if (cnt1 !=0){
                           cnt1 = 1;
                          mail1(Team,v,number,description);

                                }}

                                        else
         if ( v == "3")      {
          Integer cnt1 = count1.get(new Team(Team, v,number,description));
           if (cnt1 == null) {
           cnt1 = 0;
          }
          else
         if (cnt1 !=0){
               cnt1 = 1;
            mail1(Team,v,number,description);               
            }}

    }

return builder1.toString();
}
```

I tried to store in arrays but it didnt worked.

I after pass above parameters, i need to store the value of the number. i need to store the number so that next time while passing the parameters i need to check first whether the number is already passed or not if not then only i need to pass to mail.

can any one help on this

Comment: Post your real code. The current code doesn't even compile.

Comment: You could add to a `Set<Integer>` to check if the number has been sent before.

Comment: eeeeee.....what about to make this code readable? =)

Comment: hi this is small part of the code.. here i am checking for priprotiy and getting the count from another method. if count is greater than 0 i am sending mail with all the details. but while running the program.. mail sent again untill the priority issue is resolved. so i want to store the uniques Number and to check before i send the mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code very complicated understand what you are doing. But if you need check value that already been processed store it outside of the method. Create global class variable:

```
public class className {

    private final List<String> ARRAY = new ArrayList<>(); // global variable 

    public void yourMethod(String value) {
        if (!ARRAY.contains(value)) {
            mail(value);
            ARRAY.add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

I dont know your case and I can not get better example.

Comment: Based on Priority i am sending the mail with passing the information to mail. after passing the information i need to store the number. so that next time i need to check before passing so that if already passed no need to pass again

Comment: Hi i used above solution. but the program is in thread so for first time values are added in to array list after that array list is shown as empty and again mails are going repeatedly @ Lugaru

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the value in a "class level" variable. Whether the variable type needs to be static or instance will depend on your implementation of the method.

If you can post a sample code, we can help further.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare with 2 equals and not 1

Instead of

```
if( Team = A )
```

you need this way

```
if( Team == A )
```

Using Team = A, your saying that every time your code reaches that line it will equal Team to A.

Comment: Sorry that is correct.. but after passing the parameter value Number need to store. and next time we need to check that whether it is already sent, if so we no need to pass that

Comment: BTW this answer is not solving OP's question.

Comment: I'm just pointing an error, error: 

incompatible types
         if (Team = A){
  required: boolean
1 error

Comment: Based on Priority i am sending the mail with passing the information to mail. after passing the information i need to store the number. so that next time i need to check before passing so that if already passed no need to pass again